# What is causing this type ambiguity?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ambiguous-types

I have two relatively simple classes, `MSet`:

```
{-# Langage MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

-- A generalization of G set to Magmas
class MSet a b where
  (+>>) :: a -> b -> a

instance MSet Integer Integer where
  (+>>) = (+)

-- (+>>) constrained to a Magma
(<<+>>) ::
  ( MSet a a
  )
    => a -> a -> a
(<<+>>) = (+>>)
```

When I boot into ghci and try and test these I have an issue:

```
*Main> 1 <<+>> 2
3
*Main> 1 +>> 2

<interactive>:31:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (MSet a b0)
      from the context: (MSet a b, Num a, Num b)
        bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
                   forall a b. (MSet a b, Num a, Num b) => a
        at <interactive>:31:1-7
      The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b. (MSet a b, Num a, Num b) => a
```

While `(+>>)` works when it is constrained to a `Magma` but is ambiguous when it is not.

Now I can do:

```
*Main> :set -XFlexibleContexts
*Main> 1 +>> (2 :: Integer)
3
```

But I don't understand what is going on here or why this annotation helps.  I don't really get how the type checker disambiguates `(<<+>>)`.  If I add another instance, say `Int`, it continues to function even though it seems to be it should be ambiguous whether `1` is an `Int` or an `Integer`.

Why does one of these error and why do the other two not?

Comment: I think I've reduced it a bit more: https://repl.it/repls/SecondaryBraveFossil - question still stands: why does it pick `MSet Integer Integer`?

Comment: Note: disabling `ExtendedDefaultRules` makes both statements error out, related?

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you, I've reduced the code in the question.  I am a little embarrassed I didn't see either of those reductions when I was making the mwe.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially - you are asking GHC to solve "what is the type of `1` and `2` in the expression `1 +>> 2`, and your typeclasses mean that the answer is ambiguous.

### In depth

#### `<<+>>`

What is the type of `1 <<+>> 2`? Why, `(Num a, MSet a a) => a` of course, because GHC has to be able to turn the literals into values (`Num`) and then `+>>` them (`MSet`), and the type signature of `<<+>>` says that both literals will have the same type.

What happens when you ask GHCi to print the value of `1 <<+>> 2`? It tries to default `a` to `Integer`, which succeeds because `Num Integer` and `MSet Integer Integer`. It then evaluates the type-defaulted expression.

This is the reason the `Int` instance doesn't introduce ambiguity - GHCi isn't trying to infer the specific instance to use, it instead infers the type and then defaults the variables, leaving only the instance check.

#### `+>>`

What is the type of `1 +>> 2`? Well... `(Num a, Num b, MSet a b) => a`, it seems like. Clearly you need `MSet`, but there's no longer an assurance that `a` and `b` unify. More unfortunately, `b` does not appear in the type of the term - which is the source of the type ambiguity. The type system doesn't know which choice of `b` to use.

What happens when you ask GHCi to print the value of `1 +>> 2`? It first infers the type of the term, and gets the above type - and now it hits a type inference error before it can try to default `a` to `Integer`.

#### Why do the fixes work?

Adding type information will prevent the error

```hs
> 1 +>> (2 :: Integer) -- fine
```

because these changes eliminate the ambiguity of `b`. GHC doesn't need to infer `b`, so it doesn't get raise an inference error.

Weirdly, and I don't fully understand the reason for it, adding the annotation for `a` also seems to prevent the error

```hs
> (1 :: Integer) +>> 2 -- fine
> (1 +>> 2) :: Integer -- fine
```

though I suspect that's another GHCi-specific trick that's defaulting `b` to `Integer` in `(1 +>>) :: (Num b, MSet Integer b) => b -> Integer`. Don't quote me on that, though.

## With fundeps

It is possible to eliminate the type ambiguity using `FunctionalDependencies`

```hs
class MSet a b | a -> b where
  ...
```

though that doesn't seem like it fits your use case. This solves the inference problem because in `(Num a, Num b, MSet a b) => a`, knowing `a` will be enough to deduce `b` from the fundep in `MSet`. Later, when GHCi defaults `a` to `Integer`, it can just look up the type of `b`.